# limit results returned by distinct query

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

In my Grails app's domain model I have a 1-N relationship between Event and Performance (because many artists may perform at each event). I want to retrieve the 5 events that have most recently had a performance added.

I tried doing this with the following criteria query:

```
    List<Event> event = Event.createCriteria().listDistinct {
        performances {
            order("dateCreated", "desc")
            isNotNull("dateCreated")
        }
        maxResults(count)
    }
```

However it seems that you can't limit the result set of a distinct query using `maxResults`. Is there another way to achieve this, e.g. using HQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should this suffice?

```
Event.executeQuery("select distinct e from Event as e \
                    inner join e.performances as p \
                    where p.dateCreated is not null \
                    order by p.dateCreated desc", [max: 5])
```

If you also need `performances` corresponding to each `event` in the same query, you can use `inner join fetch`.

Comment: are you going to use an HQL for all listDistinict ?

Comment: @danielad Not really. You can use criteria as long as pagination is not used with listDistinct. They do not work together appropriately.